# RecyclerView's scrolls to top when adding items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` and I use top padding and while initially it is displayed when I get the data from the network and I add them to the adapter, `RecyclerView` scrolls to top and the padding is changed to zero.

Is there a way I can keep the top padding while I add new items ?

Xml layout :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/main_bg" android:clickable="true">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_profile_cover"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_cover_height"
        android:contentDescription="Cover image" />

    <ImageView
        android:src="@color/light_grey_with_alpha"
        android:contentDescription="Gray Overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_cover_height" />

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_profile_photo_list"
    android:clipToPadding="false" android:clipChildren="false" android:paddingTop="@dimen/profile_content_height"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post the layout and the code that you'r using ?

Comment: I have added the code for the layout. Do you need also the adapter's code ?

Comment: Make a try to replace rrot layout from FrameLayout to RelativeLayout and second FrameLayout to LinearLayout , and reply back

Comment: Seems it was an error with the call to notifyItemInserted(), as soon as I changed it to `notifyDataSetChanged()` the issue I described above disappeared. Thanks for willing to help! :)

Comment: notifyItemInserted is position based ... good that you solve it